# Clickhouse predefined http

Tags: database, clickhouse

I just found in clickhouse doc predefined HTTP. Seems to be working but what is the problem that i have to restart the whole clickhouse-server. Config is merged as i can see, but endpoint is not visible.
Anyone have such problem? Is it normal or a bug?
No matters if it is in `config.xml` or in `config.d`. Clickhouse doesn't log any problems while merging. Here is sample what I am trying.

```
<http_handlers>
    <rule>  
        <url>/distributed_files_insert</url>
        <handler>   
            <type>predefined_query_handler</type>       
            <query>SELECT value FROM system.metrics WHERE metric = 'DistributedFilesToInsert'</query>
        </handler>  
    </rule> 
</http_handlers>
```

EDIT:

I forgot about most important. CH verision: 21.3.15.4

Comment: It's normal/by design. Most of parameters in config.xml require restart. https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-server-config-files/#settings--restart . It could be implemented , but not yet.

Comment: Pity. In that form it is not that useful. Anaway thanks for reply.